# How to indicate a higher hierarchy level using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, max

I have a dataframe (`df`) in which each row represents the start (`Start`) and the end (`End`) of a specific habitat (`Habitat`) within a transect (`Transect`) and site (`Site`) in meters. It is important to note that the length of the transects varies within and among sites. As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(Site = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                 Transect = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Habitat = c("X","Y","X","Z","Z","Y","X","Z","X","X","Z","X","Y","Z","X","Y","Z"),
                 Start=c(0,2.8,3.4,5,0,1.5,5,8,12,0,2,5,7.5,0,4,8,12),
                 End=c(2.8,3.4,5,10,1.5,5,8,12,15,2,5,7.5,20,4,8,12,15))

df

  Site Transect Habitat Start  End
1     A        1       X   0.0  2.8  # Habitat `X` is between the meters 0 and 2.8
2     A        1       Y   2.8  3.4  # Habitat `Y` is between the meters 2.8 and 3.4
3     A        1       X   3.4  5.0  # Habitat `X` is between the meters 3.4 and 5.0
4     A        1       Z   5.0 10.0  # Habitat `Z` is between the meters 5 and 10.0
5     A        2       Z   0.0  1.5
6     A        2       Y   1.5  5.0
7     A        2       X   5.0  8.0
8     A        2       Z   8.0 12.0
9     A        2       X  12.0 15.0
10    B        1       X   0.0  2.0
11    B        1       Z   2.0  5.0
12    B        1       X   5.0  7.5
13    B        1       Y   7.5 20.0
14    B        2       Z   0.0  4.0
15    B        2       X   4.0  8.0
16    B        2       Y   8.0 12.0
17    B        2       Z  12.0 15.0
```

In this example, for instance, habitat `X` is twice in the transect `1` in site `A`. Also, we can observe that the total length of transects `1` and `2` in site `A` are 10 and 15 m, respectively. In site `B`, the total length of the transects `1` and `2` are `20` and `15` meters, respectively.

What I want is to calculate per `Site` and `Transect` the percentage that each `Habitat` represents with respect to all the habitats presented in terms of meters. For example, in transect `1` and site `A` habitat `X` represents 4.4 meters of a total length of 10 meters for transect `1`. In site `A` and transect `2`, habitat `X` has 6 meters from a total length of 15 meters for transect `B`.

To this aim, the first thing I do is to calculate the length (`Length`) in meters of each habitat record (=row)

```
df$Length <- df$End - df$Start
```

Then, what I want is to calculate by site and transect the percentage that the meters of an habitat represents with respect the rest of habitats and the total length of the transect. I tried this:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(Site, Transect, Habitat) %>% summarise(Porcentage = (sum(Length)/max(End))*100))
```

I want to change `max(End)` to another expression that represents the total length OF THE TRANSECT. Right now `max(End)` represents the last meter (`End`) in which a specific habitat was present. How can I include in the code above "maximum value of `End`" but within of a specific `Site` and `Transect`, but not for a specific `Habitat`.

How can I do it? My desired output would be this:

```
   Site Transect Habitat Percentage
1     A        1       X       44.0
2     A        1       Y        6.0
3     A        1       Z       50.0
4     A        2       X       40.0
5     A        2       Y       23.3
6     A        2       Z       36.7
7     B        1       X       22.5
8     B        1       Y       62.5
9     B        1       Z       15.0
10    B        2       X       26.7
11    B        2       Y       26.7
12    B        2       Z       46.7
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`, when you have different levels of hierarchy that need managing, you may need multiple `group_by()` statements.  In the code below, I use `group_by(Site, Transect, Habitat)` to calculate the total length of each habitat in the `Site` and `Transect` and then `group_by(Site, Transect)` to calculate the percentage.

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Site = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
                 Transect = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Habitat = c("X","Y","X","Z","Z","Y","X","Z","X","X","Z","X","Y","Z","X","Y","Z"),
                 Start=c(0,2.8,3.4,5,0,1.5,5,8,12,0,2,5,7.5,0,4,8,12),
                 End=c(2.8,3.4,5,10,1.5,5,8,12,15,2,5,7.5,20,4,8,12,15))

df %>% 
  mutate(length = End-Start) %>% 
  group_by(Site, Transect, Habitat) %>% 
  summarise(tot_length = sum(length)) %>% 
  group_by(Site, Transect) %>% 
  mutate(percentage = 100*tot_length/sum(tot_length))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Site', 'Transect'. You can override using
#> the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 12 × 5
#> # Groups:   Site, Transect [4]
#>    Site  Transect Habitat tot_length percentage
#>    <chr>    <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 A            1 X              4.4       44  
#>  2 A            1 Y              0.6        6  
#>  3 A            1 Z              5         50  
#>  4 A            2 X              6         40  
#>  5 A            2 Y              3.5       23.3
#>  6 A            2 Z              5.5       36.7
#>  7 B            1 X              4.5       22.5
#>  8 B            1 Y             12.5       62.5
#>  9 B            1 Z              3         15  
#> 10 B            2 X              4         26.7
#> 11 B            2 Y              4         26.7
#> 12 B            2 Z              7         46.7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In your code from above, when you are calculating the percentage, your data are still grouped by `Habitat`, so the percentage you are calculating is within the `Habitat` rather than across habitats within `Site` and `Transect` pairs.

Comment: Hi @DaveArmstrong. I am just managing some issues regarding this code. I hace a problema. Sometimes, the transect is longer than the sum of hábitats for some reasons I won't explain here. For instante, let's say that in transect 1 from site A, un row four we have as 6 as the start (instead of 5) and 10 as the end. In this case, 'sum(total_lenth)' Will be wrong since it Will give 9 instead of 10.

Comment: I could solve this easily just changing in the proposed code 'sum(tot_length)' by 'max(end)', which indicate the maximum length of a transect (it is grouped by Site and Transect). However, I got an error when I change It. I think that the column 'End' is not found un the last step. How could I do It?

Comment: @Dekike The problem is that `summarise(tot_length = sum(length))` will keep only the grouping variables and the variables created by `summarise()`.  You can include a summary for `End` in that function as well, then that would keep `End` through the rest of the pipeline.

Comment: @Dekike In answer to your first question above, If you want to summarize by `Transect`, you could do this: `df %>% group_by(Site, Transect) %>% summarise(tot_length = max(End)-min(Start)) %>% mutate(percentage = 100*tot_length/sum(tot_length))` - is that more what you're looking for?